# How to add a scrollbar in a EditText dynamically/programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-edittext, scrollbar

I know how to adda scrollbar through the xml properties such that there is a bar in the right side of the edittext field once we write stuff in it by making `setSingleline(false)`.

My question is :-

is there a way to do the same through the activity , that is, dynamically?
for eg:-

Code is :-

```
public class abc extends Activity
{

EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

edit.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

edit.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled();
}
```

These two does not work. When i add these , i still am not able to see the scrollbar on the rightside of the Edittext when i scroll..

Through XML, when we add :- `android:scrollbars="vertical"` , then we are able to see the scrollbar..

I am asking for a **WORKING** way to do it through the activity dynamically or in other words programatically

Please its urgent. I would sincerely be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

In XML

```
 android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

Dynamically/programatically:

```
edit.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Hi, When i do this, i am getting null pointer exception.,.,.
could you please make a project with just one activity and xml file and mail me the working project?
i am trying for the past 4 hours and i have googled almost everything still not able to work it dynamically

my mail id :- rahul.r4@gmail.com